# Bleichenbacher attack equation

Tags: encryption, rsa

In the Bleichenbacher attack, when the $|M_i−1| = 1$, we should choose $r_i >= 2(bs_{i-1} -2B)/n$ in order to increase the search performance. I don't quite understand how this $r_i$ value is calculated and how this can improve the performance. Anyone can help?
The above information can be found on https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/417.pdf page 3. And the original paper is http://archiv.infsec.ethz.ch/education/fs08/secsem/bleichenbacher98.pdf.